# Unreal engine for just 2d game development

Tags: 2d, unreal-4

I am very much interested in game development. But my pc seems to be not up to the mark for downloading UE4. These are the specs of my crappy pc:

- Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo e7500 2.93 ghz
- Ram: 4 gb DDR2
- Graphics : Nvidia Geforce Gt 730 Gddr5

Before doing big stuff like upgrading pc, I want to try with 2d game development, which doesn't require a high rig. So is there a way to download UE4 on such low pc. By the way, I prefer UE4 because of some features like node programming, and other extensive features.

Comment: I completely misread this question as "what alternate do I have to Unreal, given my PC does not support it". Your *actually* asking "how do I get the basics of Unreal to run, if I am below spec"; is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

From the UE4 FAQ section :

> What are Unreal Engine 4's system requirements? For developing with
>   UE4, we recommend a desktop PC with Windows 7 64-bit or a Mac with Mac
>   OS X 10.9.2 or later, 8 GB RAM and a quad-core Intel or AMD processor,
>   and a DX11 compatible video card. UE4 will run on desktops and laptops
>   below these recommendations, but performance may be limited.

So in reality you do not cover the recommended specs, but absolutely nothing is stopping you from downloading it and trying the engine.

Comment: But the epic games laucher tells that the grapihcs card is incompatible. but after all, I just want to be develop 2d games(for now)

Comment: well if the launcher says so then there is nothing you can do. Unreal is not a dedicated 2d engine and as far as I know you cant run it in "2D mode ". Perhaps you should consider another engine.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your computer specs doesn't cover the BASIC specs to run the program. Also, Unreal engine doesn't support 2D style games, but it supports platforming through some coding and camera positioning.

If you want to develop 2D games, I recommend the engines GameMaker:Studio and Godot. Both are easy to use but you'll be writing some code and you'll need some learning, because these engines work with "their own language", so to speak.

If you never coded anything, GameMaker:Studio is the one for you, because it supports a drag and drop feature to develop your stuff.

Again, if you really want the Unreal Engine, step up your pc specs.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to make games or LEARN to make games? Consider this very deeply and come up with a polished answer. Unreal Engine is a nice tool, but it does not always serve it's purpose. I, as a code-oriented developer try to avoid UE4 in any possible way, because it forces the user to think in a very specific way, and that is totally opposing to what I believe game development should be about: (theoretically) unlimited freedom of choice.

In regards to your question: Here's how I see it: Do you want to be able to make any possible game? Then you need a very wide skill set that is not bound to any specific interface or API. If you want to learn 2D graphics then pick up SDL/SFML/OpenGL/(whatever) books and start learning. There is nothing more satisfying than beginning at the very bottom and working your way up to the top: you'll never fear the learning curve, or the entry bar again. Try to explore every little nook and cranny of this infinite field and see what's getting you excited. As a matter of fact, most companies in game-dev avoid UE4 because, while being a very useful multi-tool, it also fixes the way developers can do their work.

On the other hand, UE4 will give an experienced developer a tool set that will increase their productivity A LOT. However, UE4 does come with a very steep learning curve, especially for developers.

As an example, consider that in UE4 you can't use the C++ Standard library in the way you might be accustomed. You need to either create your own algorithms and data structures or use the built-in functionality, such as the TMap or the TArray, which you need to study very closely before you are able to build anything with them. You might say that you can avoid coding completely, by using Blueprints, but you should be aware that Blueprints bring a powerful performance overhead: they are meant to be an interface between designers and programmers, not a programming tool.

TL;DR: UE4 is a next-gen game engine that has a high hardware impact even though you only want to use part of it's functionality(that is, you get the whole minimal package at all times), and has a very steep learning curve especially if you're a programmer. Before doing anything with UE4, I recommend you try to learn with a 2D wrapper for OpenGL or DirectX. Try SDL, or SFML. Or you could go for OpenGL directly(it's very satisfying to climb the initial learning curve and draw your first 3D cube that spins around in the post 3.3 standard).

I hope you'll consider what I mentioned above and won't stop pursuing the elevation of your creativity and experience.